# Redirecting the page to another html script and execute php script in background

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

i have a requirement in which user need to upload a file and click on submit after uploading the page. after clicking on submit a php script runs in the background. what i want is that the page should be redirected to another PHP page while script.php script should execute in the background.

```
<form action=script.php method='POST'>
```

what i want is that the script.php script should still run and the page should be redirected to some result.html page.. Any idea?

Comment: WHy do you want to redirect to another page? Why not use ajax file upload

Comment: can't u rederict to some other page(result.html) in script.php `header('location:'sumthng.php');`.. after you have finised doing everythng in the php script...

Comment: No i can do that since i am updating every even of php script in database and i want those changes to reflect on html page.which is auto refresh after every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

as fare as I understood your question you need a message queue tool. 
save the requests in a sql table or as jobs on a file system and
run a script from the console.

otherwise you block some web server instances.

something like rabbitmq

all the best

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Jquery file uploading method? So while ajax uploads the file, you can show something else in background div.

Comment: Hope you must have idea of jquery file uploading method

Comment: yeah i have but the thing is that there is a php page which is getting all updates and showing them to user from database what ever script.php is doing and it is not about uploading the file, that script.php is taking care of many other validations and database queries.what i want is that at the moment user submit a file it should go to that php script where we are showing the execution updates of script.php. one more thing there are many operations in script.php and at the end of each operation we are saving those into database for showing it through other php script

Answer (score 0):

You can do a header("Location: foo.php"); after the script that you want to run. If you script doesn't output any headers, this is fine and it will redirect when the script completes.

If the script is very time-consuming, you will need to do an asynchronous call, probably via ajax, to the PHP script as you submit the form, and then the form target can be where you'd like the redirection to be.

Comment: yeah script is time consuming and so can't use header thing. what i want is to redirect the user to that php script where i am showing the execution result. can it be possible through AJAX? give me some link so that the moment script.php will be called it will redirect to result page with out stopping its own execution

Comment: You can have the form action go to your redirected page, and your script as a seperate file. Have an Ajax call that will run onSubmit of your form, or onClick of your form submission button. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
header('location:'sumthng.php');
```

giv this in ur action page